# How do you get the bot to detect the embed it sent and allow the user to use a specific command in Discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want to make a combat system with my discord bot and I am trying to allow anyone to attack once the proper embed has been sent. What I have right now is an event that sends a goblin by random chance. I also have a command that "punches" the goblin but the event script and the punch script are in two different folders. I want the player to be able to punch the goblin only when the goblin embed appears. I tried checking for the title with this code:

```
if (message.embeds[0].title.toLowerCase() === 'goblins') {
  //
}
```

but it didn't work since the title was undefined. I tried fetching for the last message but I got:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Here is my code for the goblin event:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
// it is the x in y/x
const goblinChances = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19];
// const client = new Discord.Client();
// client.embed = embed;
const goblinEmbed = {
    color: 0x0099ff,
    title: 'Goblin',
    description: 'Aggressive. It has a knife. It does not seem too powerful',
    image: {
        url: 'https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/fantendo/images/1/10/BokoblinBotWSplotchless.png/revision/latest?cb=20180108050759',
    },
    timestamp: new Date(),
};
module.exports = {
    name: 'message',
    execute(message) {
        //randomizes it
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * goblinChances.length);
        //this is the y in y/x 
        //let index = 0;
        console.log(index); 
        if("MessageIDS") {
            //Should put a while loop like while(goblinHealth < 0) { running randomization and sending the embed }
            if(index == 0) {
            message.channel.send({ embed: goblinEmbed });
        }
    }
},  
};
```

Here is the code for the punch command:

```
module.exports = function(msg, args)
{
  const ID = msg.author.id;
  const fs = require("fs")
  const goblinHealth = require('../goblinHealth.json')
  goblinHealth[ID] -= 2; 
  fs.writeFileSync('../goblinHealth.json', JSON.stringify(goblinHealth)); 
  //msg.reply(goblinHealth[ID]);
  
  const health = require('../health.json')
  health[ID] -= 1; 
  fs.writeFileSync('../health.json', JSON.stringify(health));
  msg.reply(health[ID]); 
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help. If there is any other scripts, I will be happy to provide them.

Comment: Are you able to add more details about where exactly the error arose? A stack trace would be helpful.

Comment: You most probably missed a closing bracket somewhere in the code, which is a common cause of `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`.